# ¿Cómo mostrar pares de manera decreciente en ciclo?

Tags: java, bucle-for, bucles, lógica

Vuelvo con el mismo trabajo, pero con otra consigna,
en este caso tengo que mostrar los números pares utilizando un ciclo `for` de manera descendente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
int numeroFin4 = 14;

//Ciclo que muestra los pares
for (int numeroInicio4 = 5; numeroInicio4 <= numeroFin4; numeroInicio4++)
{
    if (numeroInicio4 % 2 == 0)
    {
        System.out.println(numeroInicio4++);
    }
}
```

Me faltaría saber como mostrarlo de manera descendente.

Comment: `for (int i = numeroFin4; i >= numeroInicio4; i--) { ... }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(numeroFin % 2 == 1)
{
    numeroFin--;
}

for(int i = numeroFin; i >= numeroInicio; i -= 2)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Para evitar tener que hacer varias veces el cálculo del resto de la división, lo primero que hacemos es preguntar si la **variable numeroFin** es par o impar, de ser impar se decrementa su valor en **1**, de ser par se queda como está. Posteriormente se hace un **ciclo for** que se decrementa de **2** en **2**, y se imprime cada índice del **ciclo for**, que solo serían valores pares.

Answer (score 2):

Un `for` tienes muchas formas, la forma usual es (pero ojo hay otras):

- Elemento inicial
- Condición de iteración
- Movimiento del contador

En tu caso,  el elemento inicial es `numeroFin`, la condición es que el contador sea mayor o igual `numeroInicio`, y en vez de sumar restas el contador.

Es decir empiezas desde el final y vas restando hasta llegar al principio

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int numeroInicio = 5;
     int numeroFin = 14;
     for (int i = numeroFin; i >= numeroInicio; i--){
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```